# Why are multiple calls to fillRect() slower than one call to fillRect()?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why is it that this:

```
var rows = 80
var cols = 120
var tw = 5

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        context.fillRect(j*tw, i*tw, tw, tw)
    }
}
```

runs so much slower than this:

```
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

when they fill in the same number of pixels? I naively thought that `fillRec()` was just filling in a bunch of pixels, but obviously it's doing something else. What else is it doing?

Comment: For each call there's going to be a lot of input variable type conversion, parameter validation, calls into whatever graphics engine they are using, etc, etc that will soon outweigh the actual pixel drawing. Furthermore, the pixel drawing may have optimisations for drawing 4 or 8 pixels in a single instruction, which you cannot take advantage of when doing a pixel at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scan line algorithms there is a lot of code that optimises the rendering of pixels. The current transform is applied, then the clipping, then edge sorting, This must happen before the pixels are written. They are most efficient as pixel count increase.

To improve the speed and have the GPU render pixels, render the first rect then copy that via the drawImage calls as follows.

```
var rows = 80;
var cols = 120;
var tw = 5;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, tw, tw);
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        if(i+j !== 0){
            ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0,tw,tw,j*tw, i*tw, tw, tw);
        }
    }
}
```

Will be faster than all the fillRect calls.

Though the improvement will not compare to a single render call, drawing bitmaps uses the hardware to render pixels, while fillRect is much more reliant (in full or part I am not sure of the method used) on software rendering

Comment: What does the `if(i+j === 0)` do?

Comment: @NickFegley Stops the code from drawing over the first rectangle.. Oh my bad should be !==